# What is the limit of $y = (1+10^{-x})^{10^x}$ as $x$ approaches infinity & find whether the limit will exist or not.

Tags: calculus, limits

My Work-

We are required to find the limit of $y$ as $x$ tends to infinity ,

So I assumed $x$ as infinity but I am unable to proceed further and solve the equation

I also tried L hôpital method by differentiating the numerator and denominator but I am unable to solve the limit of $y$

I even plotted a graph for this particular question but no clues can be gathered in solving the limit for $y$

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hmmm.... Well $10^x \to \infty$ as$x \to \infty$ and $\log_{10}y \to \infty$ as $y\to \infty$ so strikes me that if we replace $10^x$ with $y$ we have $\lim_{x\to \infty}(1 + 10^{-x})^{10^x} = \lim_{\log y\to \infty} (1+\frac 1y)^y = \lim_{y\to \infty} (1+\frac 1y)^y$.  I would think.

Comment: This is very e-z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have,
$$\begin{align}L &= \lim_{x\to \infty}(1+10^{-x})^{10^x}\\& =\lim_{x\to \infty} \exp{10^x\log(1 + 10^{-x})}\\& = \exp{\lim_{x\to \infty} 10^x\log(1 + 10^{-x})}\\& = \exp{\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log(1 + 10^{-x})}{10^{-x}}}\\&\overset{LH}= \exp \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{1 + 10^{-x}}\cdot 10^{-x} \log(10)}{10^{-x} \log(10)}\\& =\exp\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1 + 10^{-x}} \\&= \exp\frac{1}{1 + 10^{-\infty}}\\&= \exp\frac{1}{1 +0}\\&=\exp1\\& = e\end{align}$$

So the limit simplifies to $e$.

I've used L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate it.

Comment: Thank you for this solution!

Comment: @NikolaiRomanovBelliovichksky Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

We are trying to find

$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{10^x}\right)^{10^x}$$

HINt: One definition of $e$ is

$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Do you see how these two are related?

Comment: I did not understand the relation.Can You please elaborate it further for me please?

Comment: "I did not understand the relation"  You can see the relation between $(1+ \frac 1{\color{red}{10^x}})^{\color{red}{10^x}}$ and $(1 + \frac 1{\color{green}n})^{\color{green}n}$?  What if you simply replaced $\color{red}{10^x}$ withe $\color{green}n$?  Do you really not see the relation?

Comment: Yes I got it now. 10^x is related to n.

Comment: Thank you I am able to solve now!